# How to create an array of page items in oracle apex using java script?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I want to store page items name into an array. But i do not want to add all names by typing. Is there any package or method available that hold information of items in apex? That we can access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const myPageItems = [];
allItems = apex.page.forEachPageItem;
allItems( $( "#wwvFlowForm" ), function( el, name ) {
        myPageItems.push(name);
    }, true );
```

There was a [blog](https://blog.neilfernandez.com/loop-through-all-page-items-in-apex/) about this a while ago

Comment: Thanks @Koen Lostrie.

Comment: No problem, can you mark the question as "answered" please ?